# React Native: when I run `npm i`, some dependencies in package-lock.json are different from package.json

Tags: react-native, npm, node-modules, package.json, package-lock.json

In my React Native project, I have a specific version of a library, specifically `react-native-permissions@1.1.1`, that I need to use in the project. When I run `npm i react-native-permissions@1.1.1`, everything works fine, but if I re-build the project with `npm i`, even though `package.json` has `react-native-permission@1.1.1`, in `package-lock.json`, it gets resolved to `react-native-permissions@1.2.1`.

**What I Want To Know:**

a) Why would the actual version get resolved to 1.2.1 instead of 1.1.1?

b) Is there a way to enforce that `npm i` will install 1.1.1 instead of 1.2.1?

Comment: have you tried deleting package.lock json and nodemodules and tried with a fresh install?

Comment: @GauravRoy Yes, that's what I do before running `npm i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you npm install a specific package, say npm i permissions@1.1.1, it gets resolved with a caret before it in Package.json, so in your package.json it will be written like this

```
"permission": "^1.1.1"
```

Which means “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0.

If you want to keep the specific package only  during installs, then remove the caret before the version. or use "--save --save-exact" flag during npm install

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Do you know under what circumstances ^1.1.1 would get resolved to a higher version? Is it just if another package requires it?

Comment: If a higher version is released and available, npm will install it